# Schur‘s Lemma if only one representation is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

The version of Schur‘s Lemma I now states:

For a finite group $G$ and irreducible representations of that group on two complex, finite vector spaces $\rho_1$ on $V_1$ and $\rho_1$ on $V_2$.
Then any homomorphism $\varphi: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ s.t. $\varphi \ \circ \ \rho_1 = \rho_2 \ \circ \ \varphi $, is either $0$ or bijective (if $V_1 = V_2$ then $\varphi$ is a multiple of the identity).

By looking at the proof I was wondering whether an altered version would also hold. Is it true that if only $\rho_2$ is irreducible, then $\varphi$ is surjective and if $\rho_1$ is irreducible $\varphi$ is invective? I couldn’t find anything on this in my book and would be happy if someone could confirm this before I use it in my exam or something:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that only $V_2$ is irreducible, you can prove surjectivity by applying the argument proving Schur's lemma to the cokernel of $\varphi$. Similarly when $V_1$ is irreducible, you can apply the argument to the kernel of $\varphi$.

Edit: Actually, these are already the two pieces of the proof of Schur's lemma if you examine exactly where you use the irreducibility hypothesis on $V_1$ and $V_2$.